# How to paint on walls in Camera View android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, vuforia, glsurfaceview

I am trying to paint a wall in my Camera View. Can Anyone tell me where should I start, Any library or something helpful that can point me in right direction.

I know its a difficult thing to do but I need some direction to continue my work. Currently I have only tried with [VuForia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-Android-Development) but I don't know how we can use it with Wall recognizing and paint on walls on Augmented Reality.

Below is the required result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: OpenCV is my suggestion https://opencv.org/platforms/android/ OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library) is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android.

Comment: Did you get your solution for this question? Can you share?

Comment: @Waqas Ahmed Khan is ka solution mila?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib the only solution is to create your own solution!

Comment: @WaqasAhmedKhan have you succeeded in it?

Answer (score 3):

As you say answering your question is not easy because there are multiple solutions to achieve what you want.

I think you should read about Object Detection especially about Convolutional Neural Nets (CNN). Good libs for the detection task are probably [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) and Googles [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/android_build). Also samples in Googles [Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started) can show you how to have a live feed from the camera and manage overlaying it with your paintings. [This](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-codelab/ocr-reader-complete) example I personally found very helpful to see where/how to implement a detector as well as a graphic overlay even if its for Text Recognition. Finally [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) you have the Android Tensorflow demos.

But as easy as it seems it's still a long way to go. For this kind of implementation with Tensorflow you need to...

1. Collect sample images with walls and what is not a wall ;)
2. Think about preprocessing e.g. rescale, grayscale and filter and implement it
3. Write and tune your Python code for your CNN model
4. Train and evaluate your model with Python
5. Port your model to Android
6. Paint on the appropriate area

Another approach I can think of would be with [Edge Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) and [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) but I suggest you to use Neural Nets because results are probably better, Tensorflow (Mobile or Lite) is already optimized for Android and it's cutting edge tech ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: what would tensorflow output be?. It would detect a object. say a wall. then you would create a overlay and paint?

Comment: @Raghunandan did you find the answer?

Comment: @Weaboo no. but the above answer is what you should follow